# Guard clause causes arduino program to hang

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a program on the Controllino Automation Maxi (Arduino Mega) that uses a guard clause in an if statement.

The only thing is that, if the clause evaluates to true, and the return is executed, the Controllino restarts. I'm not sure why.

```
  #define CHILLER_TEMP_UPPER_THRESH 16.0
  #define CHILLER_NOMINAL 8.0

  if (chillTempOutlet >= CHILLER_TEMP_UPPER_THRESH)
  {
    if (hasChillCriticalNotifSent) return; //don't send notification if it has already been sent
      
    sendTempCriticalNotifcation(CHILLER_NOMINAL, chillTempOutlet);
    hasChillCriticalNotifSent = true;
  }
```

While experimenting I put `return 0;` instead and I got this warning:

```
src\main.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
src\main.cpp:1065:43: warning: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
     if (hasChillCriticalNotifSent) return 0;
```

Which leads me to believe the return actually exits the `loop()` function instead of the if statement and on the Arduino I think that means it exits into nothingness?

How can I use a guard clause on in this instance? I could create an and in the first if but is there anything else I can do and is my original theory about exiting into nothingness correct?

Comment: C supports `goto`.  Use it wisely to exit deep loops.  Learn your keywords.  Downvote for complete lack of research into the language control structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` returns from the calling function or method.

`break` breaks out if a `while, do`, or `for` block.

An `if` or `else` block ends at the closing brace, if there's an opening one.

> the return actually exits the loop() function

Correct. Be happy you got the warning. And your Arduino doesn't *hang*. The end of loop is just the start of the next one.

Comment: So how can I break out of the if statement?

Comment: With correct block design and eventually another `if` ???

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to check if it was not sent, and only then you execute that other bit of code.

```
    if (chillTempOutlet >= CHILLER_TEMP_UPPER_THRESH)
    {
      if (hasChillCriticalNotifSent == false)
      {
           sendTempCriticalNotifcation(CHILLER_NOMINAL, chillTempOutlet);
           hasChillCriticalNotifSent = true;
      }   
    }
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid nested if's but thanks!